# Find last consecutive digit sequence in string with Applescript

Tags: applescript, command-line

In my script I have strings like `G014_1998_24.jpg` or `G024_2006_08.jpg`. From these strings I need to extract the *last* consecutive digits via Applescript. So in my example strings I would need to retrieve the sequences `24` or `08` (the latter preferrably with the leading zero).

Is there any way to do this with an Applescript?

Edit: The strings could also look like this: `G014_1998.jpg`, `G014_1998_A.jpg`, `G014_1998_AB.jpg` etc. (in these cases the script should always retrieve `1998`). So I am really looking for the last digit sequence and cannot rely on the position of these digits, as I cannot predict the positions.

Comment: They eventually will be in a loop. However, I will take care of the loop structure myself, that's not what I am having issues with. So I need to know how to extract the last digit sequence from a *single* string (that could take all of the above forms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible methods:

#### Pure AppleScript

```
    set alphabet to "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

    set the text item delimiters of AppleScript to ¬
        {space} & characters of the alphabet & {".", "_"}
    set a to text items of "G024_2006_08.jpg" as text
    set b to text items of "G014_1998_AB.jpg" as text

    get last word of a --> returns "08"
    get last word of b --> returns "1998"
```

#### Help from Bash

If your filenames are even more complex, use `do shell script` and a regular expression match:

```
    set filename to "G014_1998_AB.jpg"

    return do shell script (["echo ", filename, ¬
        " | egrep -o -e '\\d+' | tail -1"] as text)

    --> returns "1998"
```

*Thanks to [@user3439894](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/115523/user3439894) for suggesting I implement* `tail` *as part of the shell script instead of using AppleScript's* `get last paragraph of` *command.  It's a little bit slicker.*

Comment: If you're going to use `do shell script` why not process it so what's returned is what's wanted and do it in two lines of code not four, e.g. `set theString to "G014_1998_AB.jpg"` and then `set theNumber to do shell script "egrep -o -e '\\d+'<<<'" & theString & "' | tail -1"`

Comment: @user3439894 I do prefer your way, in fact.  Mind if I update my answer to use your suggestion ?  Or is the etiquette such that the alternatives given should remain as comments so the OP can see what was offered versus suggested improvements ?

Comment: Feel free to use it. :)

Comment: While I find this answer, and it's comments interesting...I don't see these solutions as being able to address the situation of:  What if the filenames are all items of a generated list of files, like this... {"G014_1998_24.jpg", "G024_2006_08.jpg", "G024_2006_13.jpg", "G014_1998.jpg", "G014_1998_A.jpg", "G014_1998_AB.jpg"} that the OP would like to pass to the rest of the script to process?

Comment: @wch1zpink, I don't see where you've quoted that from.  If anything, I see a possible connection to a comment against the question that specifically states that looping through a list is *not* the issue: *"They eventually will be in a loop. However, I will take care of the loop structure myself, that's not what I am having issues with. So I need to know how to extract the last digit sequence from a **single** string (that could take all of the above forms)"*

Comment: @CJK , I just reread the OP and you are correct.  He does mention single string.  BUT... I am interested in seeing the solution to this scenario I mentioned LOL

Comment: @wch1zpink, the solution is a trivial one: wrap the code in a `repeat with` loop that sequentially processes the text string of each filename and renames each file to the returned string.  I feel you're envisioning a problem that's more complicated that it actually is, e.g. sorting the list of filenames when there's no need to do so (and using a scripting addition to achieve this instead of *Finder*'s `sort` command).  If you have a more generalised problem in mind, let's talk about it in a chat room and brainstorm solutions.

Comment: Thanks CJK, @user3439894 and wch1zpink for helping out. I went with CJK's bash solution in the end, which works very well for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me using the latest version of Sierra

```
property myStrings : {"G014_1998_24.jpg", "G024_2006_08.jpg"}

set strippedStrings to {}

repeat with i from 1 to number of items in myStrings
    set this_item to item i of myStrings
    set end of strippedStrings to items -5 thru -6 of this_item as string
    -- uncomment next line if u prefer integers returned instead (wont retain leading zero's)
    -- set end of strippedStrings to items -5 thru -6 of this_item as string as integer
end repeat
```

---

If you want to be able to sort your list in ascending order, this version of the script uses scripting addition [SATIMAGE Scripting Addition](http://www.satimage.fr/software/downloads/Satimage411.pkg)

```
property myStrings : {"G014_1998_24.jpg", "G024_2006_08.jpg", "G024_2006_13.jpg"}
property sortedStrippedStrings : {}

set strippedStrings to {}

repeat with i from 1 to number of items in myStrings
    set this_item to item i of myStrings
    set end of strippedStrings to items -5 thru -6 of this_item as string
end repeat
-- Uses SATIMAGE scripting addition to sort list ascending 
set sortedStrippedStrings to sortlist strippedStrings with ascending
```

Comment: Thanks @wch1zpink! However, I now realized, I should have been more specific on the possible strings that I could get. My apologies. The position of the last digit sequence is not always the same and I really need to retrieve the last digit sequenze, no matter where it occurs. See my edit above.